# Why do I have to execute javascript cells multiple times to get them to work in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

This bit of code will give me the name of the Ipython notebook it is run in,

```
# Create a variable in Javascript that we use in Python
display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("theNotebook = " + "\'"+IPython.notebook.notebook_name+"\'");'))
theNotebook
```

But I have to execute the the cell 2-3 times before it gives me the right answer. The first time I run it I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e65ff4ccad73> in <module>()
      1 # Create a variable in Javascript that we use in Python
      2 display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("theNotebook = " + "\'"+IPython.notebook.notebook_name+"\'");'))
----> 3 theNotebook

NameError: name 'theNotebook' is not defined
```

Then the second time I get:

```
'techela.ipynb'
```

Am I doing something wrong?